# Friendship relationship with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongomapper

I'm new to MongoDB, and went with MongoMapper for some associations help.

I'm quite curious since, you see, I'm trying to establish some User<->Friend relationships, and I'm a little bit confused about the difference between Document and EmbeddedDocument.

I suppose User would be a Document, but would Friend be an EmbeddedDocument for User or a Document on its own that simply gets called (many :friends) by User?

In my preliminary design, a Friend's list would only be accessible through a User.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking a basic "embed vs. reference" question that gets asked quite a bit when it comes to MongoDB. The answer is not always obvious.

Here's an extensive reply on [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662530/how-should-i-implement-this-schema-in-mongodb/4684647#4684647). Here are the official MongoDB docs on [this question](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design#SchemaDesign-Embedvs.Reference).

One of the general rules:

> "First class" objects, that are at top
>   level, typically have their own
>   collection.

In your case a Friend is probably a User object in itself. You probably don't want to Embed the entire Friend inside of the User. Instead, you probably want to keep a list of friends as an array inside of each User. (so probably the references)

Comment: Wow, that first link was really, really helpful! What a detailed answer! Thank you very much! Oh, and yes, I ended up doing precisely the same thing. I declared like this = many :friends, :in => :friends_ids, :class_name => 'User'