# Many to many relationship in MongoDB when we have specific fields

Tags: mongodb, many-to-many, relationship

[As this article suggests](http://blog.markstarkman.com/blog/2011/09/15/mongodb-many-to-many-relationship-data-modeling/) for many-to-many relationship we can save objectId on both collections(lets say user, course). The problem is that I have some specific fields for user who has taken the course like his progress on this course. In the above approach it cannot help much.

I've also read [this useful stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662530/how-should-i-implement-this-schema-in-mongodb), but here clicks is a top-level entity and has its own collection.

I have `course` & `user` collections and I have specific field like `user_progress_on_course`, `purchased_on`, `user_notes`, etc.

The question is should I take the SQL approach to have junction table to store fields mentioned above?

---

**EDIT1:**
One of the approaches can be as below, having user_course collection:
[image: User course collection]

The other approach is to embed `user_course` into user collection. As each user has at most 100 course which is ok to have then inside of `user` collection. So this design can be as below:

[image: Embedded document for course in user collection]

Now how do you suggest designing collections? What approach do you take? why?

Comment: Given the _cardinality_ here, I would store the `progress` as embedded documents for each `user`. But not knowing your exact needs, this is quite subjective and subject to discussions.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux thanks for you time :) 
Please have a look at the **EDIT** part section of the question. ;-)